# How to know if angular router has registered route

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-routerlink

I'm migrating a set of Anguar microsites info module federation based MFE architecture.

Not all apps will be migrated at once, so I have this issue to solve:

So far, all cross-microsite links were just regular `a` tags with href and full page reload was done.

Now, as MFEs are being loaded into the shell one by one, sometimes links will point to valid angular route (if MFE was lazy loaded using module federation), but sometimes not.

So, sometimes link would need to be rendered using `routerLink` directive and sometimes using `href`.

Is there a way to tell if a route e.g. `apps/admin` is valid Angular route at runtime in order to decide whether to use `routerLink` or `href`?

Comment: If your router files are fairly centralized, couldn’t you simply load the router.ts file(s) in a service ir component to test if a path is there? Might require some smart parsing but should be do-able. Also, if you use the angulararchitects mfe service, I think there is an option in there to get registered mfe routes if I remember correctly..

Comment: You may enable route tracing to debug route `{ enableTracing: true }` https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions#enableTracing

Comment: With module federation, routes are not centralised, they are loaded at runtime so there's no single routes.ts file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you really want, but you can use `router.config` and loop over it to check if certain path exists or not

```
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    console.log(this.router.config);
  }


  routeExists(path: string): boolean {
    return this.router.config.some((route) => route.path === path)
  }
```

Comment: This is it, thanks! Just seconds ago I also stumbled across this injection token that will also return all registered routes: https://angular.io/api/router/ROUTES

Comment: Is that work with nested routes? If we pass router1/route2/route3